# Covert curl request to http post request in swift and then download audio file

Tags: swift, curl

How can I convert this curl request to a proper HTTP request in swift:

```
curl --location --request POST https://$region.tts.speech.microsoft.com/cognitiveservices/v1' \
--header 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: $key' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/ssml+xml' \
--header 'X-Microsoft-OutputFormat: audio-16khz-128kbitrate-mono-mp3' \
--header 'User-Agent: curl' \
--data-raw '<speak version='\''1.0'\'' xml:lang='\''en-US'\''>
                    <voice xml:lang='\''en-US'\'' xml:gender='\''Female'\'' name='\''en-US-JennyNeural'\''>
                        my voice is my passport verify me
                    </voice>
                </speak>' > output.mp3
```

The `--data-raw` part is quite confusing.

This is what I have so far:

```
   func textToSpeech(transcript: String) async throws {
        
        let key = MICROSOFT_SUB_KEY
        let region = "eastus"
     
        
        
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://\(region).tts.speech.microsoft.com/cognitiveservices/v1") else { fatalError("Missing URL") }
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.setValue((key as! String), forHTTPHeaderField: "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key")
        request.setValue("application/ssml+xml", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("audio-16khz-128kbitrate-mono-mp3", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Microsoft-OutputFormat")
        request.setValue("curl", forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")
        
        request.httpBody = "<speak version='\''1.0'\'' xml:lang='\''en-US'\''><voice xml:lang='\''en-US'\'' xml:gender='\''Female'\'' name='\''en-US-JennyNeural'\''>my voice is my passport verify me</voice></speak>"
        
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
       
        let (_, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
        guard (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode == 200 else { fatalError("Error while fetching data") }
    }
```

And then finally, how can I download the audio file locally?

Comment: You need to send XML in body: `request.httpBody = "<speak version... </speak>"` No need to escape the single quotes (since it's the character delimitating the string in the cURL, but in Swift it's the double quote, escape double quotes if there is...)

Comment: @Larme gave it a try and received the following error: ```Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'Data?'```

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot a step: `let bodyString = "<speak version... </speak>"; request.httpBody = Data(bodyString.utf8)`

Comment: Side note with `(_, response)`, you are ignoring the `data` (the mp3) that you got, is that normal? You might want a `download` And depending what you want to do with the mp3, but you could use `downloadTask(with:completionHandler:)` instead and it will writes the mp3 into a temp file...

Comment: @Larme Thanks! Was able to get a response. I want to download the file play it locally and then delete it immediately after it was played. Can you show me some code how to do so? I'll accept it as the response if you can be so kind :)

Comment: @Larme Also, the api request returns ```777 bytes``` for the data

Comment: As I said previously, instead of `let (_, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)`, do `let (fileURL, response) = try await URLSession.shared.downloadTask(for: request)`, you have the URL with the mp3! (if there is no error, obv)

Comment: @Larme Hmmm, seems like I get this error with your code: ```Type of expression is ambiguous without more context```